# Database hosting for desktop application

Tags: c#, database, hosting

I am seeking a way to access database (sql server or mysql) via application. The tricky part is that the application (C# based) will be present on several machines and they all have to access same data, which means I have to think a way to host the database. And this is where I need help...all I find in the internet is web site databases which are not accessible in desktop apps or payed hosting ... hosting the database from my machine is also an option although I'm not sure if it is possible at all. So all sorts of options are welcome.

Comment: Could you expand some more? Requirements/Budget?

Comment: There's fundamentally no difference in writing a DB layer for desktop or web clients, unless the apps are running from trusted clients over private networks.

Comment: I mean that in some websites like http://www.000webhost.com/
when you create a DB it is not accessible in your project

Comment: There's no easy way to avoid writing a middle-tier to moderate access to the database. Just because it's a desktop app doesn't mean that the database should be exposed directly to the world. You shouldn't be accessing the DB directly from your app. You should be accessing a web-server that exposes certain operations on your DB via HTTP operations. It's the tried and tested approach. It's well supported by .Net. Take a look at WebAPI to get started. http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: You need to give ALOT more information. Can't this be hosted on your own machines - thus free?

Comment: well I'm not sure if it can be hosted by my machine as far as I know to do this I must have static IP....is there anything else? 

I'll check the WebApi

Comment: WebApi? Where has this come from!? WebApi has nothing to do with DB connections... maybe take a step back and review your requirements??

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar : the requirements seem pretty clear to me. User wants to get DB hosted by a third-party hosting company somewhere out there on the internet. As such, exposing the DB directly to the internet is considered *bad practice*, and a middle-tier is required. The best option IMO for the middle tier is WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @spender - I think I may have gotten confused along the way. I missed your comments RE WebAPI too!!

Comment: @spender got it right. I will read more about WebAPI and see how to implement the hosting part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine with SQL server.

The only requirement for code accessing a database is that it can actually access it (i.e. establish a connection to the DB).

I've done a project recently whereby all computers (7 in total) were already connected in a small office network. One of these computers was chosen as the host and acted as the DB server, whilst the code on all other 'client' computers contained a connection string that pointed to this one host; I get the impression this is what you're after.

With that in mind, develop your application as though the DB were local (I would actually recommend you do code against a local SQL server instance during dev) and worry about the data access later when it comes to amending the connection string (as long as you're sure you will have the facilities in place to allow this connection).

I would recommend you factor in some additional time for installation of configuration of your SQL server if you're new to this. It won't be a massive task, but don't underestimate it if you're working off time estimates.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure if the machines will be in one network and in one physical place...but this is nice idea

Comment: To be honest, guaranteeing the machines are networked in some way (even via the internet) is the ONLY idea. For each instance of the application to connect to the DB it must be, in some way, connected to the machine hosting the DB.

Comment: This is the closes to what I really want to do. 
Ok so they have internet access can I have more info on how to execute the thing. Should I connect them in some way? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343.aspx) gonna do the trick for me?

Comment: Indeed. You're barking up the right tree. If you need any further help post specific questions as new threads and I'll do my best to help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I'll test and if I have difficulties I will post new one :)

Answer (score 1):

Data access is an application independant issue.

It shouldn't matter if your application is desktop-based or web-based, as both (web and desktop) would use C#, they use the same code to access the database.

It also wouldn't matter if it was on the same machine or the other end of the world, it would (probably) go over TCP/IP, to connect.

What do you do, totally depends on needs/budget.

Comment: well to sum it I need like 100MB database and if it is possible for free.

Comment: Azure? Aws free tier?

Answer (score 1):

**Website Database accessed by Desktop Application!** I wrote a set of simple PHP pages that provide query access from my MySQL database on a remote web server to my desktop windows forms application. These pages use small PHP scripts to provide insert, select, update, and delete capabilities. The C# desktop app posts sql statements via System.Net.Http.HttpClient to these web pages. The pages perform the sql and return information to the System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage object.

In the case of select statements, the php has a small script that converts the database rows to XML to return to the response object. You can then use a System.Data.DataSet to import the XML string by the ReadXml method.

My website has a fixed IP and an SSL certificate. The scripts demand https://... and reject any request made with just http://...

Because of the round trip data access time, the application is a little slower than if the database was on a local server. You can secure access by requiring certain credentials in your post requests.

A benefit is that independent users can access the data without having to be on a particular network.

For you as the developer, it may be easier to develop windows desktop apps with complex UI operations than trying it on a website.